# Светом или цветом?

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика

1. Его глаза горели зеленым цветом/светом.
2. Ее глаза светились желтым цветом/светом.
3. Светофор горит зеленым цветом/светом.
4. Лампочка мигает красным цветом/светом.

Какое слово нужно использовать в подобных предложения: цвет или свет? Я запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что если есть глагол излучения (горел, сиял), то следует использовать слово **"свет"**.

По БТС:

- > Свет — лучистая энергия (электромагнитные колебания в определённом
  > диапазоне волн), воспринимаемая глазом и делающая видимым окружающий
  > мир.
- > Цвет — это "свойство тела вызывать зрительное ощущение в соответствии
  > со спектральным составом отражаемого или испускаемого им видимого излучения".

**Я делаю из этого вывод, что, к примеру, *"красный свет"* означает *"свет красного цвета*". Точно так же мы говорим *"красная машина"* или *"красное полотенце"*.**

P. S. Возможно, при использовании глагола *"светить"* стоит использовать *"цвет"*, во избежание тавтологии: *"Ее глаза светились желтым цветом"*. Либо и вовсе: *"Её глаза светились жёлтым"*.

Comment: Спасибо. А если мы понимаем фразу буквально (допустим, мир фэнтези): "Глаза монстра горели зеленым светом/цветом"? И правильно ли я понимаю, что использование слов "светились" и "светом" в одном предложении - это не ошибка?

Comment: "Горели зелёным светом", конечно, лучше звучит. Что касается "светились" и "светом" в одном предложении, то я бы счёл это тавтологией, но в литературе такие примеры вполне себе встречаются, как у классиков 19 века, так и у современных авторитетных писателей.

Comment: Спасибо. Стало понятнее.